# TCP Port 999 Garcon

Tags: windows, tcp

I did an NMAP today on Desktops at different sites. Some of those Desktops show TCP port 999 being open with Garcon. I then ran wireshark (5-10 mins) and saw no traffic going to/from it. Does anyone have any information on what port 999 Garcon is for/doing?

Thank you.

Comment: many of the ports below 1024 were registered for software/protocols that are long dead, so looking up the IANA port-numbers list is often not helpful for less than common ports.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run `netstat -aon | find ":999"` - it'll show you the process ID of the listening process.

Then you open Windows Task Manager and look for that PID under *Details* (may require right clicking on the column header and *Select*ing PID).

Comment: That worked! Thank you so much. Turned out to be FortiProxy